# How to make datepicker float above input box instead of below by default

Tags: vmware-clarity

I am using Clarity css framework and by default, datepicker box will appear below input box. Is it possible to make it display above when there is not enough space at the bottom? I ran into a problem where the datepicker box only display the upper half of itself because there is not enough space at the bottom.

Comment: This is an issue I’m working on. It affects all of our components that have popover behavior. I’ve created a utility that can intelligently reposition the popover if it’s outside of the viewport and applied it to all of the datagrid popovers. That PR should land in master soon. After the utility is published i will start converting the rest of the popovers to use it (datepicker jncluded).

Comment: @Hippeelee thanks for the update. Please give me an update when you are done if possible

Comment: - I am rebasing master onto the topic branch so it should land there in the next week or two. I'll try to remember to post here when it gets released and the version it is in. fyi - I'll also be migrating it back to v1 but that will take additional work so will be handled in different PR's.